# Duplicate GET request from multiple IPs - can anyone explain this?

Tags: security, web-server

We've seen a pattern in our webserver access logs which we're having problem explaining.

A GET request appears in the access log which is a legitimate, but private, url as part of normal e-commerce website use (by private, we mean there is a unique key in a url form variable generated specifically for that customer session).

Then a few seconds later we get hit with an identical request maybe 10-15 times within the space of a second.

The duplicate requests are all from different IP addresses. The UserAgent for the duplicates are all the same (but different from the original request).
The reverse DNS lookup on the IPs for all the duplicates requests resolve to the same large hosting company.

Can anyone think of a scenario what would explain this?

EDIT 1

Here's an example that's probably anonymised beyond being any actual use, but it might give an idea of the sort of pattern we're seeing (it's from a search query as they sometimes get duplicated too):

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Jun/2013:21:42:57 +0100] "GET /search.html?search=widget&Submit=Search HTTP/1.0" 200 5475 "http://www.ourdomain.com/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Jun/2013:21:43:03 +0100] "GET /search.html?search=widget&Submit=Search HTTP/1.0" 200 5475 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Jun/2013:21:43:03 +0100] "GET /search.html?search=widget&Submit=Search HTTP/1.0" 200 5475 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Jun/2013:21:43:04 +0100] "GET /search.html?search=widget&Submit=Search HTTP/1.0" 200 5475 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Jun/2013:21:43:04 +0100] "GET /search.html?search=widget&Submit=Search HTTP/1.0" 200 5475 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Jun/2013:21:43:04 +0100] "GET /search.html?search=widget&Submit=Search HTTP/1.0" 200 5475 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Jun/2013:21:43:04 +0100] "GET /search.html?search=widget&Submit=Search HTTP/1.0" 200 5475 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Jun/2013:21:43:04 +0100] "GET /search.html?search=widget&Submit=Search HTTP/1.0" 200 5475 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Jun/2013:21:43:04 +0100] "GET /search.html?search=widget&Submit=Search HTTP/1.0" 200 5475 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Jun/2013:21:43:04 +0100] "GET /search.html?search=widget&Submit=Search HTTP/1.0" 200 5475 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [21/Jun/2013:21:43:04 +0100] "GET /search.html?search=widget&Submit=Search HTTP/1.0" 200 5475 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30"
```

UPDATE 2

Sometimes it is part of a checkout flow that's duplicated to I'd think twitter is unlikely.

Comment: Do you have an actual example of this?

Comment: We've seen URLs that get tweeted shortly thereafter get hit by a dozen or two bots that monitor Twitter's status stream for links to compile analytics on them. Any possibility of this?

Comment: Yep, that's way too anonymized. You should check out the IP addresses. Or if you want an actual answer from us, provide something to work with.

Comment: I was just wanting to know if people have seen anything similar.
I'm not sure if it's legitimate customer activity so don't want to post the IPs.. what can say is the reverse DNS for all (except the original) resolve to various .serverloft.eu addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely these are ad bots reading your customers cookies and therefore trying to scrape data for tailored ads. michael hampton had a good approach, look for a pattern in the ip addresses and also do in depth investigation on a selection of address as well - look up the whois information you might be even able to call and ask the webmaster why get requests are coming from his ip.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not really familiar with how ad bots operate. Have you got any good sources of information about them?

Comment: I'm no expert myself, but its a fairly simple algorithm, when an ad banner loads up, it checks cookies for any recent shopping site or checkout, and then loads an ad based on the users apparent browsing history

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_targeting